# Save custom values from Woocommerce checkout as custom order meta data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I have a checkout page (review order) with custom data.
I need to find a hook to register some custom data (`$totaleiva_1` and `$totalefinitocarrello`) in the order and then I have to send them in email new order.

I'm not able to make it for instance. Any advice or help please?

---

Edit - That is my code:

```
$totaleiva_1 = 0; 
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart(); 
foreach($items as $item ) { 
    $totaleiva_1 += $totalForSebeneArray[$item ['data']->get_id()]; 
} 
$totaleiva_1 = number_format($totaleiva_1, 2, '.', ''); 
$totalefinitocarrello = $totaleiva_1 + $total; echo "&euro;"; 
echo $totalefinitocarrello;
```

Comment: any advice? Thanks for help

Comment: Could you show us more code as `$totaleiva_1` and `$totalefinitocarrello` doesn't help.

Comment: $totaleiva_1 = 0;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach($items as $item ) {
    $totaleiva_1 += $totalForSebeneArray[$item ['data']->get_id()];
}
$totaleiva_1 = number_format($totaleiva_1, 2, '.', '');
$totalefinitocarrello = $totaleiva_1 + $total;
echo "&euro;"; echo $totalefinitocarrello;

Comment: $totaleforsebene was calculated first with another code. In cart I have not problem. In checkout and in email order I don't see this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to **add and display 2 hidden fields** with the 2 desired values *(to be able to get and save them as custom order meta data on submission)*.

> Also your code is a bit outdated and can be simplified.

Here is your revisited code:

```
$totaleiva_1 = 0; 

// Loop through cart items
foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) { 
    $totale_iva_1 += $totalForSebeneArray[$cart_item['data']->get_id()]; 
} 

$totale_finito_carrello = wc_price( $totale_iva_1 + $total ); 

echo $totale_finito_carrello; 

// Display 2 hidden input fields
echo '<input type="hidden" id="totaleiva1" name="totaleiva1" value="'.$totale_iva_1.'">
<input type="hidden" id="tfcarrello" name="tfcarrello" value="'.$totale_finito_carrello.'">';
```

Then you will **save that data** as custom order meta data using:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_order_custom_meta_data', 10, 2 );
function save_order_custom_meta_data( $order, $data ) {
    if( isset($_POST['totaleiva1']) && ! empty($_POST['totaleiva1']) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_totale_iva_1', esc_attr( $_POST['totaleiva1'] ) );
    }
    if( isset($_POST['tfcarrello']) && ! empty($_POST['tfcarrello']) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_totale_fin_carrello', esc_attr( $_POST['tfcarrello'] ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Now to get that data and use it anywhere:

1) **from the order ID** variable, use:

```
$totaleiva_1 = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_totale_iva_1', true );
$totalefinitocarrello = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_totale_fin_carrello', true );
```

2 from the WC_Order Object:

```
$totaleiva_1 = $order->get_meta('_totale_iva_1');
$totalefinitocarrello = $order->get_meta('_totale_fin_carrello');
```

---

To display those in Woocommerce new order notification, ou will use:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'email_order_details_action_callback', 5, 4 );
function email_order_details_action_callback( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    if( $email->id === 'new_order' ) {
        if ( $tiva1  = $order->get_meta('_totale_iva_1') ) {
            echo '<p>'. __("Totale IVA") . ': ' . $tiva1 . '</p>';
        }

        if ( $tfcarr = $order->get_meta('_totale_fin_carrello') ) {
            echo '<p>'. __("Totale finito carrello") . ': ' . $tfcarr . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Display the fields in Admin order pages:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'admin_order_after_billing_address_callback', 10, 1 );
function admin_order_after_billing_address_callback( $order ){
    if ( $tiva1  = $order->get_meta('_totale_iva_1') ) {
        echo '<p>'. __("Totale IVA") . ': ' . $tiva1 . '</p>';
    }
    if ( $tfcarr = $order->get_meta('_totale_fin_carrello') ) {
        echo '<p>'. __("Totale finito carrello") . ': ' . $tfcarr . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Now I think that all **your IVA custom calculations can be handled by Woocommerce** using available settings possibilities, as you are making things Much more complicated everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for help.  the last question: **in what page I put echo hidden, point 1 and point 2?** Thank you so much.

Comment: In linkedin probably my associate catches you. Sorry for misunderstanding. I asked: in what page I put echo hidden, point 1 and point 2? Thank you so much. And obviously I accept.

Comment: I asked the page because this code doesn't work. Thanks for your time and patience

Comment: I'm sorry for the trouble but I'm not able to add echo hidden. My code $totaleiva_1 = 0; is in cart-total.php. :(

Comment: @RosannaLaMalfa I repeat,Is not possible for me to test your code with my additions, so  as I don't know where and how you display it on checkout page.

Comment: But I don't want you test. Please sorry for misunderstand. I add in my function.php `// Outputting the hidden field in checkout page
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'add_custom_checkout_hidden_field' );
function add_custom_checkout_hidden_field( $checkout ) {
    // Output the hidden field
    echo '<input type="hidden" id="totaleiva1" name="totaleiva1" value="'.$totale_iva_1.'">
<input type="hidden" id="tfcarrello" name="tfcarrello" value="'.$totale_finito_carrello.'">';
}` but the values are 0. Only this question. Thank you

Comment: @RosannaLaMalfa Note that: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without **a clear problem statement are not useful** to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"*… Questions/answers are for everybody usage, so they need to be useful and testable.