# Does WooCommerce Add Filter on functions.php Change The Actual Output Data?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to create an automation that stores WooCommerce order data into Airtable with Integromat/Make (https://www.make.com/en). This data includes Customer Billing and Shipping Address details.

As everyone here presumably knows, WooCommerce does not use the complete state/province/country name. Instead, WooCommerce uses an abbreviation such as US for United States (of America), IN for India, ES for Spain, etc. The same goes for states: IL for Illinois in US, PB for Punjab in India, V for Valencia in Spain, etc.

The Customer database on my Airtable uses the complete state/province and country names. Thus, I have done my homework and applied these codes to my functions.php file:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_countries','custom_country', 10, 1);

function custom_country($mycountry){
    $mycountry = array(
        'AF' => __( 'Afghanistan', 'woocommerce' ),
'AX' => __( 'Åland Islands', 'woocommerce' ),
'AL' => __( 'Albania', 'woocommerce' ),
'DZ' => __( 'Algeria', 'woocommerce' ),
'AD' => __( 'Andorra', 'woocommerce' ),
'AO' => __( 'Angola', 'woocommerce' ),
.
.
.
 );
    return $mycountry;
}
```

and

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'custom_woocommerce_states' );

function custom_woocommerce_states( $states ) {
  $states['ID'] = array(
'AC' => 'Aceh',
'SU' => 'Sumatra Utara',
'SB' => 'Sumatra Barat',
'RI' => 'Riau',
'KR' => 'Kepulauan Riau',
'JA' => 'Jambi',
.
.
.
'PB' => 'Papua Barat'
  );

  return $states;
}
```

to hopefully change the province/state and country name.

However, the pulled data on Integromat/Make shows otherwise. The Billing and Shipping state/province and country are still showing the abbreviation. It seems as if the code above does not do anything.

Please find attached a screenshot of the data on Integromat/Make

[image: Data as shown on Integromat/Make]

Am I doing something wrong in my code? Or perhaps, is what I'm trying to do even feasible on WooCommerce?

Look forward to hearing your thoughts on this,

Thanks!

Anthony.

Comment: Why no just save new order meta data with full names and access that ?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your suggestion. By using order meta data, do you mean [this] (https://prnt.sc/BMm59I_jikSH)?

Comment: I dont know what i should look in that image but i mean this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55043577/save-custom-values-from-woocommerce-checkout-as-custom-order-meta-data

Comment: Hi, I am trying to show that the meta data array does not contain meaningful information that I can use to display full province/state/country name.

Thank you for your link. I will read it and apply it to my use case. Will reply when I have questions or need to confirm with you. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Like i said you can always add more data to your order when you create the order in form of meta. With woocommerce_checkout_create_order you have access to $order, $data and from there you can add new meta like $country = $order->get_billing_country(); $state = $order->get_billing_state();  $country_name = WC()->countries->get_states( $country )[$state];  $order->update_meta_data( '_full_name_country', $country_name ); . I havent tested it but something like that.